# TkInter: draw one pixel

Tags: python, tkinter

In *TkInter*, we can draw several [shapes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#). But what if we just want to draw a pixel instead ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After creating a `Canvas` object, you can draw a line that spans a single pixel.

```
your_canvas_widget.create_line(x, y, x + 1, y)
```

Comment: i'm guessing this will draw two pixels but i could be wrong. can you use `(x, y, x, y)`?

Comment: @JulienSpronck That is what I am looking for too. Nothing in the documentation. When I try what he said `x+1` (or `y+1`) I see a point but it looks like a 2 pixels width (or height) point. When I do what you suggest, I can not see the pixel drawn (may be this is normal given the human eye and screen resolution ?)

Comment: @JulienSpronck No. It would be a line of width zero in that case.

Comment: @Nakkini This will create a line of width one.

Answer (score 3):

To create a single pixel with co-ordinates `x, y` on a canvas, you can use a `rectangle`object:

```
canvas.create_rectangle( (x, y)*2 )
```

By default, the rectangle object has a one-pixel wide black border, which when one-pixel wide will just be black, regardless of the colour. To give the pixel your desired colour, you can use `outline=""`, so you can then specify your `fill` colour.

I prefer this method as you only need to provide the `x, y` co-ordinates, no `x+1` is needed.

Answer (score 3):

This topic is already answered and quite old but I'd like to add a comment, maybe it is of interest:

```
your_canvas_widget.create_line(x, y, x + 1, y)
```

Is what I have also tried and it works for me. I used it for creating an image of a Mandelbrot-set. It works quite fine for small resoltions, e.g. 200 x 200 pixel. But for larger resolutions, the TK engine seems to have problems to render those many "micro lines". the calculation of the mandelbrot set is finished, but the Tk window seems to hang without rendering anything.

A better solution for drawing pixels, I have found in [python-mandelbrot-fractal-with-tkinter](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/579048-python-mandelbrot-fractal-with-tkinter/). There the pixels are put one by one into a tkinter **PhotoImage** which is afterwards rendered all in one, very fast.